# Retrieve Instagram video embed URL from API

Tags: api, video, embed, instagram

I'm trying to find to programmatically get the embed link for an Instagram video. Unfortunately, it appears that Instagram's oEmbed endpoint, treats videos as photos, and only returns the key frame image, rather than providing an embed link.

Does anyone know of a way to retrieve the embed link for an instagram video without having to manually visit the page for that video?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Instagram's API site](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/) a **GET /media/media-id** request for a video object returns a JSON object with the information you need in "data.videos.low_resolution.url".

I successfully embedded the video returned by their sample request into a web page with the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Video Embed Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video width="480" height="480" controls>
    <source src="http://distilleryvesper9-13.ak.instagram.com/090d06dad9cd11e2aa0912313817975d_102.mp4" 
      type="video/mp4"/>
    </video>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I hadn't realized before that the `/embed/` URL was just using HTML5 video, not a Flash embed or anything. So this is definitely an appropriate solution, and more flexible than the one that I had found.

Comment: `GET /media/{media-id}` is [deprecated since April 2018](https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/#april-4-2018)

Answer (score 8):

I was not able to find a way to *retrieve* the embed URL, however upon examining the embeds that Instagram provides, I was able to determine how to *generate* it based on the information provided by the Media API endpoint. Basically, you just need to append `/embed/` to the end of the short url for the piece of media. So it would look something like this in a Django template:

```
<iframe src="{{ media.short_link }}embed/" width="612" height="710" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

As an interesting side note, I also discovered that you can change the width and height in the embed code, and it works without any problem (at least when you just halve the dimensions, I didn't try anything else).

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to get the Instagram Video URL is to add `?__a=1` at the end of the post you're trying to target (i.e. `https://www.instagram.com/p/BqTd8dhFKLN/?__a=1`).

You can then navigate to `["graphql"]["shortcode_media"]["video_url"]` or `["graphql"]["shortcode_media"]["edge_sidecar_to_children"]["edges"][carousel_number]["node"]["video_url"]` (depending on whether the post is a carrousel) which will give you the video URL.