# Instagram feed that plays videos

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

I have created an Instagram feed that pulls in images and videos using a hashtag. I know form looking at Instagram on my phone that the videos are being pulled in I done this using JavaScript is it possible to play the videos on my site without opening another window thanks

**Update**

my JavaScript so far

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    clientId: '467ede5a6b9b48ae8e03f4e2582aeeb3',
    limit: 16,
    get: 'tagged',
    tagName: 'teamRousey',
    sortBy: 'most-recent',
    after: function () {
        var images = $("#instafeed").find('a');
        $.each(images, function(index, image) {
            var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms';
            $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay);
            $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay);
            $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay);
            $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay);
            $(image).css('animation-delay', delay);
            $(image).addClass('animated flipInX');
        });
    },
    template: '<video controls ><source src="{{video}}embed/" type="video/mp4"></video>"<div class="likes">&hearts; {{likes}}</div>'
});

feed.run();
```

Comment: Stupid question deserves stupid answer: Yes it's possible

Comment: Well it's not a stupid question to me because I didn't know That's why I asked is this difficult to do can it be done through javascript

Comment: Show us what you got so far.

Comment: Basically. 1) get the video src. 2) play it in a `<video>` tag

Comment: I can help you tomorrow If you still need help after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791448/retrieve-instagram-video-embed-url-from-api) or someone else dosen't helps you. But its 2AM here and i'm going to bed now. You know if it's a video or a images so it's doable

Comment: Ye that would be goo d if i dont  get it thanks

Comment: I could no solve this what I  tried was adding to the template as I am displaying the instagram items in a grid and i want the videos to play in that grid when I click on them @Endless

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here we go.

```js
jQuery(function($){

    var feed = new Instafeed({
        clientId: '467ede5a6b9b48ae8e03f4e2582aeeb3',
        limit: 16,
        get: 'tagged',
        tagName: 'teamRousey',
        sortBy: 'most-recent',
        after: function () {
            
        },
        resolution: 'standard_resolution',
        filter: function(image) {
            if (image.type == 'image') {
                image.template = '<img src="' + image.images.standard_resolution.url + '" />';
            } else {
                image.template = '<video width="100%" controls loop><source src="' + image.videos.standard_resolution.url + '" type="video/mp4"/></video>';
            }
            return true;
        },
        template: '<header>{{model.template}}</header><footer><a href="http://instagram.com/{{model.user.username}}">@{{model.user.username}}</a><br>{{caption}}</footer>',

    });

    feed.run();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jsonp.afeld.me/?url=http%3A%2F%2Finstafeedjs.com%2Fjs%2Finstafeed.min.js"></script>
<div id="instafeed"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect Thanks Very much I tried  voting your answer up but I don't have enough rep points but i appreciate the help