# Instagram API to get mp4 video list and show it on web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, instagram, instafeedjs

I have been looking for a jquery or javascript based API for Instagram that will get the list of .MP4 file name which i can show on website.

I am not good with java-script and have gone through several website trying to figure it out. So far i am not been able to find a single complete example that can which will get the list of .mp4 videos based on account name or userID.

How can i use `https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` to get an list of videos

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791448/retrieve-instagram-video-embed-url-from-api)

[Reference 2](http://www.picssel.com/play-mp4-videos-with-mediaelement-js-in-fancybox/)